# Getting file listings

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to retrieve all the files in some directories. Here is my original code:

```
    Private Function Search(path As String, Recursive As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim fileObject As FileSystemInfo

    If Recursive = True Then
        For Each fileObject In dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
            If fileObject.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory Then
                Search(fileObject.FullName, Recursive)
            Else
                lstFiles.Items.Add(fileObject.FullName)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For Each fileObject In dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
            lstFiles.Items.Add(fileObject.FullName)
        Next
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

This code works well, yet it returns some directories and I am wanting to only return files.

I tried this code:

```
    Private Sub Search(ByVal path As String, ByVal Recursive As Boolean)   
    if not Directory.Exists(path) then Exit Sub

    Dim initDirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(path)

    For Each oFileInfo In initDirInfo.GetFiles
        lstfiles.items.add(oFileInfo.Name)
    Next

    If Recursive Then
        For Each oDirInfo In initDirInfo.GetDirectories
            Search(oDirInfo.FullName, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

However, i get the following error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Application Data\' is denied.

Can someone help me with my original code, or help me access these directories with my new code?

thanks

EDIT:

I have added this module to get it working:

```
Imports System.Security.Principal
```

Module VistaSecurity

```
'Declare API
Private Declare Ansi Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As String) As Integer
Private Const BCM_FIRST As Int32 = &H1600
Private Const BCM_SETSHIELD As Int32 = (BCM_FIRST + &HC)

Public Function IsVistaOrHigher() As Boolean
    Return Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6
End Function

' Checks if the process is elevated
Public Function IsAdmin() As Boolean
    Dim id As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim p As WindowsPrincipal = New WindowsPrincipal(id)
    Return p.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
End Function

' Add a shield icon to a button
Public Sub AddShieldToButton(ByRef b As Button)
    b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System
    SendMessage(b.Handle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, &HFFFFFFFF)
End Sub

' Restart the current process with administrator credentials
Public Sub RestartElevated()
    Dim startInfo As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
    startInfo.Verb = "runas"
    Try
        Dim p As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return 'If cancelled, do nothing
    End Try
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: OK, all done. Was very easy. I added this line: "If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileObject.FullName) Then"

Comment: Actuallly, not all done. I am still getting these errors: "Access to the path 'C:\Users\UpdatusUser\' is denied." How can I list these files, and also copy them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access denied errors are occurring at Windows Libraries I think. I don't think there is any way to list the file in these libraries as they aren't actually folders.